# MPI "Bad Termination of one of Application Processes, Code:11"

Tags: c, mpi, transpose, termination

Actually I have a problem which has made me crazy and still I'm not to resolve it even after surfing the net and applying many suggestive changes. If someone can help, I really appreciate.

I have a program for matrix transposition in C language and I have to parallelize it by MPI. The compilation is successful but when I run it, I get :

> Bad Termination error, code 11.

I paste the code below for you to be able to see and then I write for you also the command which I'm using to compile and run on cluster:

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define DIM 128 // global A[DIM], B[DIM]

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
  int ncpus, my_rank, i, j, iblock;
  int Nx, Ny; // Nx=DIM/ncpus, Ny=DIM, local array: A[Nx][Ny], B[Nx][Ny]
  double **A, **B, *Ctmp, *Dtmp;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ncpus);

  if(DIM%ncpus != 0) { // make sure DIM can be divided by ncpus
    if(my_rank==0)
      printf("ERROR: DIM cannot be divided by ncpus!\n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    return -1;
  }

  Nx = DIM/ncpus;
  Ny = DIM;

  // allocate memory
  A = (double **) calloc(Nx*Ny, sizeof(double));
  B = (double **) calloc(Nx*Ny, sizeof(double));
  Ctmp = (double *) calloc(Nx*Ny, sizeof(double));
  Dtmp = (double *) calloc(Nx*Ny, sizeof(double));

  for(i=0;i<Nx;i++)
    for(j=0;j<Ny;j++) = A[i][j] = 2*(my_rank*Nx+i) + j;

  // divide A into blocks --> Ctmp; A[i][iblock*Nx+j]  Ctmp[iblock][i][j]
  for(i=0;i<Nx;i++) 
    for(iblock=0;iblock<ncpus;iblock++)
      for(j=0;j<Nx;j++)
        Ctmp[iblock*Nx*Nx+i*Nx+j] = A[i][iblock*Nx+j];

  // local transpose of A --> Dtmp; Ctmp[iblock][i][j]  Dtmp[iblock][j][i]
  for(iblock=0;iblock<ncpus;iblock++)
    for(i=0;i<Nx;i++)
      for(j=0;j<Nx;j++)
        Dtmp[iblock*Nx*Nx+i*Nx+j] = Ctmp[iblock*Nx*Nx+j*Nx+i];

  // All-to-all comm --> Ctmp
  MPI_Alltoall(Dtmp, Nx*Nx, MPI_DOUBLE, Ctmp, Nx*Nx, MPI_DOUBLE,
              MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  // merge blocks --> B; Ctmp[iblock][i][j]  B[i][iblock*Nx+j]
  for(i=0;i<Nx;i++)
    for(iblock=0;iblock<ncpus;iblock++)
      for(j=0;j<Nx;j++)
        B[i][iblock*Nx+j] = Ctmp[iblock*Nx*Nx+i*Nx+j];

  // clean up
  free(A);
  free(B);
  free(Ctmp);
  free(Dtmp);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

command for compiling:

```
mpiicc MatrixTransposeMPI.c
```

where `MatrixTransposeMPI.c` is the name of my program

command for running:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

where `./a.out` is the name of output made by compilation command

Comment: Should `A = (double **) calloc(Nx*Ny, sizeof(double));` be using `sizeof (double*)`? Or better, `sizeof(*A)`? And, you don't seem to have allocated any memory for each row. You have allocated enough memory for a 2D array and expect the compiler to magically resolve `A[i][j]`, when it doesn't know the row size.

Comment: Also this line `for(j=0;j<Ny;j++) = A[i][j] = 2*(my_rank*Nx+i) + j;` does not compile.

Comment: Going back to the first comment, I would expect to see `A = calloc(Ny, sizeof(double*)); for(int y=0; y<Ny; y++) A[y] = calloc(Nx, sizeof(double));`

Comment: Dear friend, I just tried your first suggestion for changing argument of sizeof, but the error is still the same. can you please give me more detailed suggestion for your second idea about memory of each row? I'm not good in C programming. that will be helpful if you write me down what exactly I can change or add and then try it. Thank you in advance

Comment: yes your're right about the line of for(j=0;j<Ny;j++) = A[i][j] = 2*(my_rank*Nx+i) + j; actually I made a mistake when I was pasting this line here. even without extra "=" , still I have the same error

Comment: What about my 3rd comment (which will also apply to `B`)? Without allocating a pointer to each row, `A[i][j]` won't work, because `A[i]` is `NULL`.

Comment: you declare `A` as a (jagged) 2D array, but you allocate it as a 1D array. You will find several questions on SO related to allocating 2D arrays in contiguous memory. Or you can simply use modern C and declare `double A[Nx][Ny];`

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet oooh now I've got the poiiint, I defined A as Nx*Ny dimension but I tried to fill it linearly! Thank you, I will change it and we will see